# DB2 how do I replace a double quote returned by an XML element

Tags: db2, xquery-sql

I am able to successfully retrieve the value of XML element using the following SQL

```
*SELECT XMLQUERY('$item/*:ItemSpec/*:AdditionalDescription/*:ABCDescription/text()' PASSING productval.value_xml as "item") AS H_DESCRIPTION FROM USER1.XMETA*
```

This returns a value that has double quotes (") in it. How do I replace it with a different value in the same select query. I tried something like this but it didn't work

```
Select REPLACE(XMLQUERY('$item/*:ItemSpec/*:AdditionalDescription/*:ABCDescription/text()' PASSING productval.value_xml as "item"),'"','QUOT') AS H_DESCRIPTION
```

The error is No authorized routine named "REPLACE" of type "FUNCTION" having compatible arguments was found...SQLCODE=-440,SQLSTATE==-42884.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XMLQUERY returnes an XML type, try casting it to varchar before applying REPLACE on it:

```
REPLACE(XMLCAST(XMLQUERY('$item/*:ItemSpec/*:Addition ...) AS VARCHAR(...)), '"','QUOT') AS ..
```

Comment: Thanks Lennart. Casting it to Varchar worked for me.